# Server Push JSF page to client

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jsf-2, richfaces, cdi

For my Java EE 6 (Richfaces 4.1) based application I am trying to achieve this: the user opens a browser window which makes a long poll until a given REST service is invoked (the rest service will receive a facelets name together with a list of parameters). As a result of the Webservice call, the JSF page is rendered in the browser with the parameters specified in the REST call.

As a proof of concern, I've first tried with AsyncContext and CDI Events and I can print the REST parameters in the browser:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Notifier", urlPatterns = {"/Notifier"},asyncSupported = true)
public class Notifier extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject
    Event<NotificationReq> events;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            AsyncContext startAsync = request.startAsync();
            startAsync.setTimeout(0);
            events.fire(new NotificationReq(startAsync));
    }
}
-------------------------
    @ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
    @Singleton
    @Path("notify")
    public class RESTNotifier {

        @PostConstruct
        public void onInit() {
            this.browsers = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<NotificationReq>();
        }
        private CopyOnWriteArrayList<NotificationReq> browsers;

        public void onNewNotificationRequest(@Observes NotificationReq nr) {
            this.browsers.add(nr);
        }

        @GET
        @Path("{message}")
        public void specific(@PathParam("message") String message) {
            for (NotificationReq notificationRequest : browsers) {
                notificationRequest.sendMessage(message);
                this.browsers.remove(notificationRequest);
            }
        }
    }
    -----------------------------------------------------
        public class NotificationReq {

            private AsyncContext asyncContext;

            public NotificationReq(AsyncContext asyncContext) {
                this.asyncContext = asyncContext;
            }

            public void sendMessage(String message){
                try {
                    PrintWriter out = this.asyncContext.getResponse().getWriter();
                    out.println(message);//TODO: Invoke and Render JSF instead of printing message!
                    this.asyncContext.complete();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NotificationReq.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
```

As I use richfaces, I then thought I could better do this with a4j:push: http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=push&sample=pushCdi

My questions are:

1) What you think is the best approach (I would say Richfaces, as the AsyncContext terminates as soon as the service is invoked, and I would like to have a sort of "infinite" long polling)?

2) Can you please point me to any example showing how to invoke a JSF page programmatically (this is the TODO you can see in my code)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the server already has the event use push, this is discussed online on many blogs, read this one: http://rik-ansikter.blogspot.com/2012/02/configuring-richfaces-push-with-42.html

Comment: Hi thanks for answering! I think integrating a4j:push would be no problem, what I ask here is how to let the server push a whole jsf instead of (in the example you posted) a "new Date()"...

Answer (score 0):

To let the push update some part of your page do this:

```
<a4j:push ...>
  <a4j:ajax event="dataavailable" render="whatYouWantToRerender" />
</a4j:push>
```

Comment: Sorry, but as far as I know event should be a JS event like "keyup" and render expects the id of a component in the page (e.g. render="date" with <h:outputText id="date"/>), so I don'T understand how can I load another JSF page with this..?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by loading another JSF page ?

Comment: In the above example, imagine that message = "index.xhtml": in this case index.xhtml must be rendered in the consumer browser (per rest I can pass further parameters, which will be then "converted" into form parameters and hence injected into the Request/Session beans)

Comment: The JSF logic would be: update your data in the bean on the server side during the event, then push, and the render will update the page using the updated values. Why not place the a4j:push in the page you want updated ? If you want more than one page updated put the a4j:push tag in a parent.

Comment: I wanted to try it out but unfortunately I am experiencing problems to let the showcase example run (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084298/richfaces-a4jpush-with-cdi-not-working). As soon as I solve this I will try what you suggested. Thanks!